# How to update all columns when using BigQuery DML

Tags: google-bigquery, dml

I have a Bigquery table that I want to periodically update with new data.
I was thinking of using another table and a [UPDATE query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-patterns#dml_statements_that_update_or_insert_single_rows), but it seems I have to specify all the columns I want to update.

```sql
UPDATE
  dataset.t t
SET
  my_column = u.my_column
 ...
FROM
  dataset.u u
WHERE
  t.my_key = u.my_key
```

Is there a way to write a query that will update all fields from the destination table? I have a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, there is actually now way to do it in one query.

However, if your changes concerns a specific value `VALUE` of you key *(maybe a partition ?)*, you can `delete` then `merge` :

```
DELETE FROM
FROM
  dataset.t t 
WHERE
  t.my_key = VALUE

MERGE dataset.t t
  USING dataset.u u
  ON t.my_key = u.my_key
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ROW;
```